# Razor textbox type does not work

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

using a textbox razor type seen below I can set the maxlength to 4 but when trying to set the type to number I can still enter in characters and it also allows more then 4 characters, numbers still are limited to 4. I tried

```
pattern = "\\d*"
```

that allows characters too. Doesn't work in Chrome as well as IE

```
@Html.TextBox("smsCode", null, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength="4", type="number" })
```

Comment: you can set limit in model using data annotations.

Comment: The best way is use `TextBoxFor` with `StringLengthAttribute` & `RegularExpressionAttribute` instead of plain textbox.

Comment: I'm not using nor need to use a property in the model because I'm not sending anything from this element back to the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.TextBox` generates `<input>` element, and according to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-maxlength) `maxlength` attribute is ignored when the input element has set with `<input type="number">`.

> If the value of the **type attribute** is `text`, `email`, `search`, `password`,
>   `tel`, or `url`, this attribute specifies the maximum number of characters
>   (in Unicode code points) that the user can enter; **for other control
>   types, it is ignored.**

Hence you need some workaround to achieve numeric input with maximum length:

1) Remove `type="number"` attribute from `TextBox`/`TextBoxFor` helper and make sure you have `id` for the textbox.

```
@Html.TextBox("smsCode", null, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength="4", id="smsCode" })
```

2) Use `keydown` DOM event to block any other inputs than numeric values and special keys against the textbox (use jQuery for example, based from *@SpYk3HH*'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/995193/)).

```
$("#smsCode").keydown(function (e) {
    // Allow some keys: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter etc.
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
        // Allow select all
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
             // Allow home, end, left, right, down & up keys
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
                 return;
        }

        // Ensure the input has numeric values
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

Afterwards, check if generated textbox accepts only numeric values.

Working example: [DotNET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bzmsYj)

Comment: how about a different element to use to restrict to a 4 digit number. I don't have to use textbox.

Comment: Which element you want to have something like `maxlength`? The most important thing you need is handling `keydown` event so that only numeric values are allowed.